# Make an equivalent of a "For" loop

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to figure out a way to capture information that's essentially a "For" loop in the programming world. I have one sheet that contains unique names and unique quotes:

```
SHEET 1

Column A    Column B
========    ========
John        Hello       
Mike        Hi
Paul        Hey
Joe
```

And then I have another sheet with multiple names, multiple quotes and a number of times quoted (where 0 times does not exist) and the sheet will continue to add new names and quotes every hour:

```
SHEET 2

Column A    Column B    Column C
========    ========    ========
John        Hi          2
John        Hey         1
Mike        Hello       8
Sean        Hey         4
Paul        Hi          1
Jane        Hello       2
John        Hello       1
...         ...         ...
```

**OUTPUT EDIT:**

Add the number of times that `John`, `Mike` and `Paul` quoted `Hello` found in Sheet 2, Column C

Add the number of times that `John`, `Mike` and `Paul` quoted `Hi` found in Sheet 2, Column C

Add the number of times that `John`, `Mike` and `Paul` quoted `Hey` found in Sheet 2, Column C

```
SHEET 3

Column A    Column B
========    ========
Hello       9
Hi          3
Hey         1
```

Comment: Not particularly... maybe my logic is off. I guess the unique identifier would be the quote in Sheet 1, Column B.  

I want to be able to find everyone who said `Hello`, `Hi` and `Hey` out of all of the people in Sheet 1, Column A. 

So I guess in reality, the output would be:
`Hello = 9`(from `Mike` and `John`), `Hey = 1` (from `John`) and `Hi = 3` (from `John` and `Paul`)

Comment: I should also mention (which I edited the example) to only select those people who are in Sheet 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pivot table from Sheet 2 with ColumnB for Rows, ColumnC for Values and ColumnA for Filter. Adjust filter to select only `John`, `Mike` and `Paul` then lookup `Hello`, `Hey` and `Hi` in Sheet1 from the pivot table with say:

```
=vlookup(B2,'Pivot Table 1'!A$1:B$3,2,0)
```

in Sheet1 B2 copied down to suit.

Comment: Almost worked. The issue I have is that I need to find someone (Sheet 1) who may not necessarily be on Sheet 2, but could be in the future. Like `Joe`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time explaining it as I keep forgetting certain variables. Sheet 1, Column A would have those three names plus `Joe` - That will never change. But Joe hasn't quoted anything yet, but he might in the future. If he does, I'd like to capture him as well.

Comment: I'll never care about `Sean` or `Jane` (or the other 7 billion - 4 people)

Comment: Or maybe `John` hasn't quoted anything yet, but when he does, I need to include him.

Comment: Either way, this answer allows me to at least see who's quoted something already and filter by them. Which is a major help!